# Moving from Java 7 to Java 8, issue with long iteration

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to migrate a stupid idiot 4 call of ForEach in Java8 with lambda expression / stream but I am struggling

Here is what I have done (replaced name for better understanding)

```
companySiteList.stream()
.filter(companySite -> companySite.getId().equals("ID"))
.map(obj -> obj.getEmployeeList().stream()
    .filter(employee -> employee.getId().equals("ID_EMPLOYEE"))
    . ... ???
)


private void orderFurniture(Company company, Employee employee) {
    // code
}
```

What I need is to call the function orderFurniture for this employee that match both filter. There is only one employee that can match both filter

Edit :

This is the original code I am trying to migrate

```
for(Company company : companySiteList) {
    if(company.getId().equals("ID")) {
        for(Employee employee : company.getEmployeeList()) {
            if(employee.getId().equals("ID_EMPLOYEE")) {
                orderFurniture(company, employee);    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You know there's nothing particularly *wrong* with the original code.

Comment: In fact, the original code is a lot more readable than any Stream-based solution.

Comment: @VGR exactly. Put that in a well named method in a relevant class and you've got good design on your hands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` instead of `map` to get a `Stream` of all the `Employee`s that pass both filters, and then call the method using `forEach`:

```
companySiteList.stream()
               .filter(companySite -> companySite.getId().equals("ID"))
               .flatMap(obj -> obj.getEmployeeList
                                  .stream()
                                  .filter(employee -> employee.getId().equals("ID_EMPLOYEE")))
               .forEach(emp -> orderFurniture ("ID","ID_EMPLOYEE"));
```

This relies on your assumption that "There is only one employee that can match both filter". Otherwise the method would be called for multiple `Employees`.

OK, if you need to pass the actual objects to the method call, you have to store the `Company` of the relevant `Employee`:

```
companySiteList.stream()
               .filter(companySite -> companySite.getId().equals("ID"))
               .flatMap(obj -> obj.getEmployeeList
                                  .stream()
                                  .filter(employee -> employee.getId().equals("ID_EMPLOYEE"))
                                  .map(emp -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Company,Employee>(obj,emp)))
               .forEach(entry -> orderFurniture (entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()));
```

Comment: Sadly it's not, it's a private function declared outside of Employee entity. Can't put a method that call external WebService in the Entity

Comment: @kinaesthesia Can you show how that method is called in your old Java 7 code?

Comment: @kinaesthesia so you can simply call `orderFurniture ("ID","ID_EMPLOYEE")`

Comment: Yah I guess my simplification is bad. Let's say I have to call it like that : 
orderFurniture (company, employee). I need both object. Sorry can't post the original code since it's not mine ^^

Answer (score 2):

Two things are important:

1. Do exactly what you mean to do. You need to filter sites and employees, not map them to another value. So don't use `map()`.
2. The arguments from the outer level of nesting are available for the inner level of nesting.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Test {
    interface Employee {
        String getId();
    }

    interface Site {
        String getId();

        List<Employee> getEmployeeList();
    }

    ;

    private static void orderFurniture(String companyId, String employeeID) {
        // code
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Site> companySiteList = new ArrayList<Site>();

        companySiteList.stream()
                .filter(companySite -> companySite.getId().equals("ID"))
                .forEach(site -> site.getEmployeeList().stream()
                        .filter(employee -> employee.getId().equals("ID_EMPLOYEE"))
                        .forEach((e) -> orderFurniture(site.getId(), e.getId())));

    }
}
```